# Displaying Qlikview Dashboards on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, qlikview, mashup

I wanted to know how to publish my Qlik View Dashboards on SharePoint sites.

I could no find any documentation where I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't look very far...

[QlikView Community I](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-3561)

[QlikView Community II](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-7882)

[QlikView Community III](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview-developer/12.0/Subsystems/QlikViewWorkBench/Content/Sharepoint2013Support.htm)

etc., etc.